# Avoiding Recompilation with annotations

Tags: java, compilation, annotations

Can annotations be changed at run time without having to recompile the code?

Comment: Almost certainly not, as they're embedded in the bytecode (and in fact, not all annotations are retained beyond compilation).  Why would this be useful?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My question was along the lines of deploy on save features that many Java EE vendor(s) are touting about. I am not clear if annotations address this.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations can't be changed at runtime at all, let alone without requiring recompilation. Your question is meaningless.

Comment: What about hot code reloading like JRebel? This is probably overkill for the OP's purposes, but theoretically it should work, no?

Comment: (I feel like I should clarify this: Even if it works, you still need the recompilation, but you can swap at runtime.)